# Error trying to use restFB on GAE development environment

Tags: java, facebook, google-app-engine, restfb

I'm trying to use restFB on Google App Engine, when I try and get info about the current User, I get an error,

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not verify SSL certificate for: https://graph.facebook.com/me?format=json
```

Below is the code I am using,

```
FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient();
    User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
```

What do I need to do to get this working on the development server?

Comment: I think this is because I am working on the development server. What steps do I need to take to let this code run on the development server.

Comment: Let me know if you found a workaround for this please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in release 1.5.0 If you update to the new SDK it should run fine.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can use [doNotValidateCertificate()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/FetchOptions.html#doNotValidateCertificate%28%29) to ignore certificate validation. It may put your app at risk, however.